# JavaScript not being called at all. It is being loaded in the developer tools, though

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a master page that declares the `<script>` tags in this order:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body style= "margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 30px;">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Login"); }

    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I have a partial view, which I load in one of the views:

```
@using(var form = @Html.BeginForm("RequestNewVerificationCode", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmRequestNewVerificationCode" }))
{

<fieldset>
    <p>
        Email
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { id = "txtEmail" })
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="Request New Verification Code" id="btnRequestNewVerificationCode" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

<p>
    <div id= "divMessage"></div>
</p>
}

@Scripts.Render(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/RequestNewVerificationCode.js"))
```

The contents of my `RequestNewVerificationCode.js` are as follows:

```
$(document).ready(RequestNewVerificationCode.WireHandlers);

var RequestNewVerificationCode =
    {
        WireHandlers : function()
        {
            debugger;

            $("#btnRequestNewVerificationCode").bind("click", this.MakeAjaxRequest);
        },

        url: '/Account/RequestNewVerificationCode',

        MakeAjaxRequest: $.ajax(url,
            {
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(
                { 
                    'Email': $("#txtEmail").val()
                }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            }),

        OnSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        },

        OnError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    };
```

However, the break-points I put in my JS file are not being hit at all. I am not even able to debug it.

Comment: Not sure you can debug Javascript with Visual Studio

Comment: I mean in the developer tools of the browser.

Comment: Where are you putting the breakpoints?

Comment: I do that, too. This isn't the first time. I've been doing it for ages. I more or less drudge through the JavaScript part always. I hate it.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the `RequestNewVerificationCode.WireHandlers` method and that should be called by `document.ready`.

Comment: You mention `<script>` tags.  Where are they?

Comment: what if you put `document.ready` statement at the end of the file ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 - How could it possibly change anything?

Comment: This is an ASP.NET MVC app. The `@Scripts.Render` is basically a server-side method that just spits out the `<script>` tags. It maintains a dictionary of such tags that you have to register at the beginning. Those arguments to the `Scripts.Render` are dictionary keys.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 could you just try `$(document).ready(function(){ console.log('hello'); });` And check in your browser console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, got it. This one always bites me.

I recall now that in JavaScript, if you declare an object with the syntax that I am using, i.e. if you say:

```
var foo = { }; // this syntax
```

rather than this one:

```
var foo = new object();
```

Then, you cannot use foo before declaring it, i.e. JavaScript will *not* hoist that symbol. So:

```
foo.bar() // illegal because foo not yet declared
var foo = { }; // this syntax
```

whereas:

```
foo.bar(); // legal
var foo = new object(); // this syntax
```